# How do I check enchantments with commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make a command execute if the specified player is holding an enchanted book with no enchantments, command is `/give @s enchanted_book`.
I can’t find the data values on the wiki, and

```
/execute if entity @p[hasitem={item=enchanted_book,data=0}]
```

accepts any enchanted book.

Comment: You may need NBT tags for that, and Bedrock edition doesn't have them